# Using spread inside destructure assignment to get all variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In React, I have `this.props` and I have a lot of variables and want to get them using the destructuring assignment.

My question is whether or not it's possible to get ALL variables in `this.props` doing something like this:

`const { ...this.props } = this.props;`

But this is obviously incorrect. Is there any way I can get all the variables in `this.props` without having to destructure them one by one?

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Nope you can't do that, you have to name the variables in destructuring.

Comment: Keep in mind that variable bindings are created before any code is evaluated, by finding all variable declarations and function declarations upfront. That is not possible here since you'd have to evaluate `this.props` to get its value.